# Is there a way to randomly change the seed in Point Instance?

Tags: geometry-nodes, random

This created a Node group that was seeded so that the branches and leaves of the tree could be changed randomly
However, using the RandomValue node did not result in random changes
The image shows a Cube and IcoSphere connected to a Switch node for testing, but I can't seem to use RandomValue
But what I want to do is similar to this[image]

The [video](https://youtu.be/w00HThHXU30) is a modified seed